# Local Development Configuration with Git repositories

Tags: apache, git, apache2

I have my local environment configured with `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive. My virtual host config looks as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/%1/www"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/%1/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg
    LogLevel warn

    LogFormat "%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon
    ErrorLog logs/error_log

    Alias /info/ "/var/www/html/info.php"
    Alias /info "/var/www/html/info.php"
</VirtualHost>
```

So basically I put files into `sample-project/www` directory. Now wondering how should I merge this configuration and this approach with Git repositories.

I'm using gitweb to share my repos on my local LAN network. However, when the directory is `sample-project` gitweb shows it as `sample-project/.git`, but when I change directory name to `sample-project.git` it looks as I want.

I know some of more advanced users may think it's really stupid question, but this is quite important for me. I just started learning good practices, have new environment and want to know good advices.

And ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use gitweb, you need to call the gitweb.cgi script of your gitweb installation.

You will find in my [Apache httpd.conf](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf) an example of such a config (with SSL and LDAP authentication that you can ignore)

```
DocumentRoot /home/auser/compileEverything/gitweb
Alias /git /home/auser/compileEverything/gitweb
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /home/auser/compileEverything/gitweb>
</Directory>
```

You would then configure your gitweb (like for instance, [explained here](https://github.com/joemaller/Simple-Gitweb-Config)), and your [`gitweb.conf` (as shown here for example)](http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-configure-gitweb/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wondering, what structure of directories would you recommend for efficient management?

Comment: @DaveW: by structure of directories, are you referring to the directories declared in the httpd.conf, or the directories where the git repos are stored, or the directories within a Git repo data?

Comment: Just everything. I'm completely lost with all the configuration stuff right now. I'm storing all my projects in `/var/www/html/` directory. `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive allows me to use virtual subdomains however I'm wondering how I should store Git repos with this structure. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: @DaveW: when using in conjunction with GitWeb, the simplest structure is the best: you just need all your repos within one root directory, and you would reference that in your gitweb.conf as mentioned in http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-configure-gitweb/. This is very different from the `VirtualDocumentRoot`: a `DocumentRoot` is enough and reference gitweb, not the Git repos.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Last question, if you don'y mind: please clarify, I do not have to store my repositories in my projects directory tree, am I right? Could I store repos in `/var/www/git/` and projects in `/var/www/html/`? Every file changed is being uploaded into my remote machine. Would it be correct? Once again, thanks for your replies and effort!

Comment: @DaveW: regarding the repos, you can store them anywhere (that the httpd process has the right to access/write): they don't need to be within `/var/www`. Actually, my config (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf) is about declaring many `VirtualHost` (including one for gitweb), each with their own `DocumentRoot`, each completely outside the 'classic' `/var/www` main Apache http root.

Comment: Thanks. Started to analyse your logs, read more docs regarding this topic.